# Redirect Working on Module Not Menu Item

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, login

Joomla 3.9.19

I have a login module and in the Login Redirection Page I have selected a menu item > single article. This redirect works fine.

I also have a menu item type > login form. In the Menu Item Login Redirect I have selected a menu item > single article (same as above). This redirect doesn't work, I am always redirected to the user profile page.

I have tried an absolute URL in the menu item type > login form, makes no difference.

I don't have any other login componetns or plugins installed.

I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260879/joomla-3-login-redirect-works-in-login-module-but-does-not-working-from-compon) and a few other places.

Any ideas why this could be or how I can redirect to an article on both the login module **and** the login menu item? I don't want to edit core files, and I dont think I should need an override for such a basic task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was the change the *Login Redirect Type* to an Internal URL, **and** ensure it was non-sef.

This is in the documentation https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_redirect_users_after_a_successful_login%3F

> Due to a security fix on Joomla 3.4.6, the redirect url must be an
> internal url, it must start with index.php? and be a non-sef url.
> Before Joomla 3.4.6, it worked but that was due to a bug in the way
> Joomla validated the urls. Now that security has been applied and the
> urls tested correctly the above examples will fail.

Once I change my URL to a non-sef version of my menu item it worked;

> index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=32&Itemid=469

Thanks to @Grant G for the tips.